# cURL - Open files outside server's root directory

Tags: apache, curl

I am wondering, how can I access a file **outside the root directory** of my server?

For example,  /home/username/FILE.mp3

The code i am currently using to open a file is the following:

```
<?php
$location = "ABSOLUTE-PATH/FILE.mp3";

$ch = curl_init($location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$timestamp = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
curl_close($ch);
if ($data === false) {
  echo 'CURL Failed';
  exit;
}
//Get file size
if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
}

$begin  = 0;
$end    = $contentLength - 1;

if (preg_match('/bytes=\h*(\d+)-(\d*)[\D.*]?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches))
{
    $begin  = intval($matches[1]);
    if (!empty($matches[2]))
    {
        $end    = intval($matches[2]);
    }
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{ header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'); }
else
{ header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); }

header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . $contentLength);
header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$contentLength");
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');

if ($timestamp != -1) { //otherwise unknown
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $timestamp) . " GMT");
}

ob_clean();
flush();
echo ($data);
exit;
?>
```

I know as a fact that cURL doesn't work with relative paths and i assume that a file outside the root directory is treated as a relative link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you use cURL?  Typically cURL would be something you would use to communicate with a different server via HTTP.  Why not use `file`, `file_get_contents`, `fopen` or similar?